# Create a trigger, which allows 7 entries for 1 group, and only 1 entry to be inserted for another group, based on the number of the week

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a trigger, which fires up after the record insertion. Situation is that if crimeapp = 0, I need to limit a one record related to suspect, a week, if cripeapp = 1, then such records can be unlimited. Now when I am inserting this for one particular day, it saves a record, does not allow to insert the second for that particular week, however after inserting the second record, fe, with date 2 weeks after, the third record cannot be inserted due to - TOO MANY VALUES. How to work this around? I want to have a 1 record, for the particular user, on crimeapp = 0, if crimeapp = 1, this can be done with day difference, respectively 7 records for the week. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Table is following:

```
INSERT INTO crimesusspects(id, suspnr, dtcr) VALUES (
1,
(select sid from suspect where sid = 7789),
TO_DATE('31/06/2022 12:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
)
```

Trigger is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_crimesusspects_primrestr
BEFORE INSERT ON crimesusspects
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

crimeapp NUMBER(10);
weekcrimenr NUMBER(10);
countchk NUMBER(10);
insertoff EXCEPTION;

BEGIN

SELECT ISPRIMARY
INTO crimeapp
FROM suspect
WHERE SID = :NEW.suspnr;

SELECT NUMBERWK
INTO weekcrimenr
FROM crimesusspects
WHERE suspnr = :NEW.suspnr;

select COUNT(*)
INTO countchk
from crimesusspects
WHERE suspnr = :NEW.suspnr AND NUMBERWK = :new.NUMBERWK;

IF ((crimeapp = 0) AND (weekcrimenr = (:new.NUMBERWK))) THEN
      RAISE except_b;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN insertoff THEN
   Raise_application_error(-20300,'NA);
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   NULL;
WHEN too_many_rows THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NA');
   Raise_application_error(-20300,' NA');
END
```

Comment: Please post your table structure and your end result with some sample data and possibly a fiddle.

Comment: Querying a table from a row-level trigger on the same table is asking for trouble. Can this not be achieved with a unique constraint?

Comment: Please can you update the question title so that it summarises the technical issue in a way that will be helpful for other developers with the same issue.

Comment: I could achieve this with creating perhaps - recordls(id, week, data), recordholders(id, fk recordls(id), but not quite sure how to limit for crimeapp = 0 ( To be exact 1 record for 1 week) and if crimeapp = 1 (unlimited, but need a 1 a day only, so 7 together).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a trigger. Use a unique index.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX crimessuspects__suspnr__dtcr_wk__uidx ON crimesusspects (
  CASE crimeapp WHEN 0 THEN suspnr END,
  CASE crimeapp WHEN 0 THEN TRUNC(dtcr, 'IW') END
);
```

Which, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE crimesusspects (
  id       NUMBER
           PRIMARY KEY,
  suspnr   NUMBER
           NOT NULL,
  dtcr     DATE
           NOT NULL,
  crimeapp NUMBER
           DEFAULT 1
           CHECK (crimeapp IN (0,1))
);
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO crimesusspects(id, suspnr, dtcr, crimeapp)
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2022-06-30', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2022-06-30', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, DATE '2022-06-23', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, DATE '2022-06-30', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1, DATE '2022-06-23', 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Works, for each `dtcr` ISO week and each `suspnr`, as there are:

- unlimited rows where `crimeapp = 1`; and
- at most 1 row where `crimeapp = 0`.

However, if you try to add a row in the same ISO week for the same `suspnr`:

```sql
INSERT INTO crimesusspects(id, suspnr, dtcr, crimeapp)
VALUES (6, 1, DATE '2022-06-28', 0);
```

When you get the exception:

> ```
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_LCZZMEHPDIMIJMHAHEET.CRIMESSUSPECTS__SUSPNR__DTCR_WK__UIDX) violated
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=99855d5d70fee3d9b308562730a083be)*

---

> What would you recommend to check out and make sure that [...] only 1 booking for crimeapp 1 is allowed per day?

You can use something like:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX crimessuspects__ca__suspnr__dtcr__uidx ON crimesusspects (
  crimeapp,
  suspnr,
  CASE crimeapp
  WHEN 0 THEN TRUNC(dtcr, 'IW') -- Per ISO week (Mon-Sun)
  WHEN 1 THEN TRUNC(dtcr)       -- Per day
  END
);
```

---

> What would you recommend to check out and make sure that the inserted date is starting from the following date [...]? I meant if any data insertion is < SYSDATE, so no option to insert data related to past.

The simplest method, if you always want tomorrow's date, is to never allow users to pass a hard-coded date in their `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements and always use `TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY`:

```
INSERT INTO crimesusspects(id, suspnr, dtcr, crimeapp)
VALUES (6, 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 0);
```

Then the value will always be tomorrow's date at midnight.

If you cannot manage that, or want to allow user to pass in abitrary future dates but not past dates, then you can use a trigger to check the date and change it to a future date (or raise an exception):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER crimessuspects__future_date__trg
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF crimessuspects
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.dtcr < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY THEN
    :NEW.dtcr := TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
    -- Or
    -- RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'DTCR must be for a future date.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

But don't use a trigger to enforce the constraint of 1 entry per user per week/day; that should be a unique constraint.

Comment: You just saved my life. Thanks a lot. I am said that I cannot put you star up. What would you recommend to check out and make sure that the inserted date is starting from the following date, and only 1 booking for crimeapp 1 is allowed per day?

Comment: @ArtursRadionovs "make sure that the inserted date is starting from the following date" I'm not sure I understand the question. However, the other part "only 1 booking for crimeapp 1 is allowed per day", I've updated the answer with.

Comment: thanks a lot for everything. Would you recommend any good source where I could learn this better? I meant if any data insertion is < SYSDATE, so no option to insert data related to past.